# What is the relationship between stiffness and stability?

Tags: classical-mechanics

It seems to me that if you have an attractive force, (so a negative sign), then if that force increases with reduced separation (so positive stiffness) then this is unstable.

If you have a repulsive force, (so a positive sign), then if the force increases with reduced separation (still positive stiffness) this is stable because an deviation from equilibrium acts to restore to equilibrium,

Is there a more general way of thinking about this or a subtlety i am missing?

Comment: Speaking about a mass attached to a spring, there is an stable position because the springs  responds to being compressed or elongated, always looking to return to its unstretched length. For the definition of stability, I would appeal to maths: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory